# Best way to read through xml

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

HI I have a xml document like this:

```
<Students>
<student name="A" class="1"/>
<student name="B"class="2"/>
<student name="c" class="3"/>
</Students>
```

I want to use `XmlReader` to read through this xml and return a list of students as `List<student>`.
I know this can be achieved as follows:

```
 List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("AppManifest.xml");
    while (reader.Read())
    {
       if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "student")
       {
            students.Add(new Student()
            {
                 Name = reader.GetAttribute("name"),
                 Class = reader.GetAttribute("Class")
             });
        }
     }
```

I just want to know if there is any better solution for this?

I am using silverlight 4. The xml structure is static, ie. it will have only one `Students` node and all the student node with above said attributes will only be there.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Absolutely - use LINQ to XML. It's *so* much simpler:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("AppManifest.xml");
var students = doc.Root
                  .Elements("student")
                  .Select(x => new Student {
                              Name = (string) x.Attribute("name"),
                              Class = (string) x.Attribute("class")
                          })
                  .ToList();
```

`XmlReader` is a relatively low-level type - I would avoid it unless you really *can't* afford to slurp the whole of the XML into memory at a time. Even then there are ways of using LINQ to XML in conjunction with `XmlReader` if you just want subtrees of the document.

Comment: I dont think Silverlight supports XMLDocument

Comment: @Chinjoo: XDocument not XMLDocument. And yes it does: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=VS.95).aspx

Answer (score 8):

It's alot easier if we're using Linq xml:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("AppManifest.xml");

var students = 
    xDoc.Root.Elements("student")
    .Select(n =>
        new Student
        {
            Name = (string)n.Attribute("name"),
            Class = (string)n.Attribute("class"),
        })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Student> students = (from student in doc.Element("Students").Elements("student")
                          select new Student { 
                              Name = student.Attribute("name"), 
                              Class = student.Attribute("class") }
                          ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the link below,

http://www.nearinfinity.com/blogs/joe_ferner/performance_linq_to_sql_vs.html

`XmlReader` is supported in Silverlight 
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189001(v=vs.95).aspx)

`XmlReader` like a `SQLDataReader` is basically a non-cached model, so they are performance oriented but you can move only 'Forward' with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(Server.MapPath("~/XML"));

    while(reader.Read())
    {
        switch(reader.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:                            
                var lbl = new  Label();
                lbl.Text=(reader.Name + " -> " );
                break;

            case XmlNodeType.Text:                                 
                Response.Write(reader.Value + "<br />");
                 break;

            case XmlNodeType.EndElement:                        
                 Response.Write("</" + reader.Name + ">");
                 break;
        }
    }
}
```