# How to de-serialize the DocuSign Connect XML response in C#

Tags: docusignapi

We are using using DocuSign Connect feature to get the recipient and envelope status updates with PDF Documents.

What is the best way to De-serialize the Connect XML response in ASP.Net WebAPi Rest Controller?

1) Adding “https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx?wsdl” to generate wsdl class files and de-serialize the Connect XML response?

2) De-serialize connect XML using DocuSign Client Library? Do we have DocuSignEnvelopeInformation in the Client Library?

3) Parse the XML and Get the statuses of recipients as well as envelopes and Documents.

Comment: Define what you mean by "best".  It will depend on your particular use case.  If you could add some detail as to what you are trying to accomplish, it would be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to read through xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195728/best-way-to-read-through-xml)

Answer (score 0):

If you like the world of SOAP, you can implement a SOAP service, and then configure DocuSign Connect to call your service. The SOAP libraries will then automatically deserialize the request (the XML notification message from DocuSign Connect) into C# structures.

Personally, I'm not a fan of SOAP. So I use an XML parsing library to give me access to the data in the XML message.

[There are a number of C# XML parsers](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=c%23%20xml%20parser%20library). Pick one that works well for you. Here's a [related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195728/best-way-to-read-through-xml) too.